# how to set phpfmt to php 5.5 mode?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I'm using php.fmt in sublime.

Several days ago, it warned me tp update my php tp 5.6 or newer, otherwise it can't work. For some reason, I can't update my php version just because sublime.
I have read phpfmt's readme docuement, it says it can word under php 5.5.x, but it didn't say how.
Can any one tell me, how to set to make phpfmt work under php 5.5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the doc.And it said likes:

1. ctrl+shift+P or cmd+shift+P
2. type in phpfmt: toggle PHP 5.5 compatibility mode
3. click it and then the phpfmt compatible to 5.5

https://github.com/dericofilho/sublime-phpfmt

Good luck.